# Import or visualize of products from a magento shop to another magento shop?

Tags: magento

I have a B2B magento shop and I want to offer the resellers that have a B2C magento shop the possibility to show/sell my products. Is there a way to do it automatically the visualization of my products in stock directly in their B2C shop?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using SOAP API

Comment: Do you have link with an example how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your B2B shop need to have a product feed system.

This feed is sent to your B2C shop.This shop will process that feed and populate/update DB which will result in your B2C site have those products in its DB.

Probably once indexing happens on your B2C shop feed products will be available in listing and search.